# Instantiating multiple variables based off of keys in map

Tags: variables, dart, variable-assignment

In Dart is there any way to instantiate multiple variables based off of the key in a map?

For example, let's say I have a map:

```
Map aMap = {"var1" : "value1", "var2" : "value2", "var3" : "value3"};
```

And I want to instantiate the variables

```
String var1, var2, var3;
```

with the values from the map. I thought I'd be able to do it someway like:

```
aMap.forEach((key,value) {
   #don't know what to do here 
});
```

But I don't know what to put in the brackets.

Comment: What is your use-case? It looks like a strange construction. Perhaps what you are trying to achieve can be done differently.

Comment: I'm pulling the values from a yaml file. I want to instantiate all the top level constructs in the yaml file as variables of the same name. A yaml file 'yaml : yaml text' would instantiate a variable yaml to "yaml text".

Comment: Does "yaml" need to be a variable? I don't see what you would actually do with that in code since you don't know the variables names up front.

Comment: Well yaml is just text, so it can't be a variable. I was just wondering if this would be possible. Guess not :\

Comment: I know, but why do you want it to be a variable? What exactly is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just use:

```
String var1 = aMap['var1'];
String var2 = aMap['var2'];
String var3 = aMap['var3'];
```

But you might as well not declare those variables, and just refer to `aMap['var$n']` for some `int n`.

Comment: I know I can do that, but imagine the map is quite large. I don't want to instantiate 10 variables that way, much less more than that. And the variables aren't named var1 var2 etc. They're named things like "match" and "patterns", so I can't do the integer method.

Comment: Can you say `aMap['match']`, `aMap['patterns']`, etc? (Without declaring variables)

Comment: hmm maybe, but the point was to avoid having to instantiate the variables by typing. More like dynamic variables named the same as the keys in the map.